# Excel Range Copy Value vs Value2 Extension Method

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vsto, extension-methods

I'm making an extension method to simplify copying range data from on worksheet to another.
I want to specify a rectangular range and the top left cell of the target range. Keeping formating is important for Dates and Currencies so I want to Use Value over Value2

```
//Extension Helper method
public static void CopyRangeTo(this Excel.Range from, Excel.Range to){
    //resize to to match the rows and columns of from
    to = to.Resize[from.Rows.Count, from.Columns.Count];
    //copy the contents of the range from to range to
    to.Value = from.Value;
}

//how its intended to be called
ws.Range["A1:C5"].CopyRangeTo(ws2.Range["B3"]);

//note this call doesn't work because Cells cannot be used statically
ws.Range[ws.Cells[1, 1], ws.Cells[5, 3]].CopyRangeTo(ws2.Cells[2,3]);
```

Currently The program works well the inital time a call the method. However if I change the worksheet at all the method seems to fail (Even if I didn't affect the ranges being used). However I have noticed that if I use Value2 instead then it is much more robust, however I lose formatting.

I may try to iterate through the cells and see if that helps, if any one has other ideas or insight between moving cells around I'd appreciated. I'd like to stay away from paste special.

Comment: what you mean "change the worksheet at all the method"? and seems the method signature of `CopyRangeTo` not as same as the one you called `(Range from, Range to)` and `(Range to)`

Comment: @Alex Testing this method I call the top line and it transfers over data from a ws1 to ws2. If I enter "test" in cell "S30" and try to run the method again then I get a runtime exception unless I use Value2

Comment: @Alex This is an extension method, the range I'm calling the method on is the implicit (Range from)